# Open new tab browser and pass value without localstorage angular

Tags: angular, base64

i need pass data of a component to other in new tab of browser without localStorage. The fist component has a struct json many complex to pass through localStorage because i'm working with image in base64 and if i use service they values are undefined. How do this?

Comment: can you add some code snippet or a stackblitz url for better understanding to debug your issue?

Comment: Hi @Anna, thanks! I don't see the need to do a simulation. did you not understand the question?

Comment: No not able to understand the exact thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an high level - NOT POSSIBLE

Opening an application in a new tab will create a whole new instance of angular running in that tab, So it is not possible to share data among two different tabs without localstorage.